# What is the technical reason that $\mathcal{L}(e^{-zt})=\int_{0^-}^\infty e^{-(x+\alpha+i(\beta+y))t}dt$ diverges when $x+\alpha=0$?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, laplace-transform

Let $z=\alpha+i\beta$ and $s=x+iy$ be complex numbers.

Consider the calculation of the Laplace transform of $e^{-zt}$.

$$\mathcal{L}(e^{-zt})=\int_{0^-}^\infty e^{-(x+\alpha+i(\beta+y))t}dt$$

Suppose $x+\alpha=0$. That is $x=-\alpha$ which means $\text{Re}(s)=-\text{Re}(z)$.

Then the integral becomes

$$\mathcal{L}(e^{-zt})=\int_{0^-}^\infty e^{-i(\beta+y)t}dt$$

$$=\left . \frac{e^{-i(\beta+y)t}}{i(\beta+y)}\right |_0^\infty$$

$$=\left .\frac{1}{\beta+y}e^{-i\left (\frac{\pi}{2}+(\beta+y)t\right)}\right |_0^\infty$$

This integral does not go to $\pm \infty$.

What is the technical reason why this integral diverges?

Comment: The Laplace transform $$\mathcal{L}_t\left[e^{-z t}\right](s)=\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-z t}\, e^{-s t}dt=\frac{1}{s+z}$$ is only valid for $\Re(s+z)>0$ because $\frac{1}{s+z}$ is a meromorphic function with a pole of order $1$ at $s=-z$.

Comment: Going to infinity is not the only way something can diverge. Divergence just means it does not converge. Like $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \cos(n)$ does not converge, even though it remains bounded.

Comment: @StevenClark what is the branch of math that I can study to understand what you wrote? What is the subject called?

Comment: I'd say complex analysis since Laplace transforms are typically valid for $\Re(s)>\alpha$ for some $\alpha$, but [Meromorphic_function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meromorphic_function) perhaps provides some clarification on what I said.

Comment: A substantially easier way to make sense of this is to realize that $e^{i(\beta +y)t} = \cos((\beta+y)t)+i \sin((\beta+y)t)$ and then note that $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \cos((\beta+y)t)$ does not exist (it keeps oscillating). No fancy complex analysis is needed.